# How not to display missing values in a multi line plot with D3js

Tags: d3.js, plot, series, missing-data

I'm trying to plot two lines from a tsv file with D3js. One series is complete, the second one has values only starting from 2005.

```
year    value1  value2
2000    8956355 
2001    8924704 
2002    8865723 
2003    8747717 
2004    8701521 
2004    8701521 
2005    8607147 11380809
2006    8551259 10672554
2007    8513818 10394369
2008    8462607 10297716
2009    8448535 9998783
2010    8411177 9988697
2011    8024205 9491908
2012    7920080 8725402
2013    7911208 8668111
2014    7807984 8274928
2015    7747598 8027083
2016    7575879 7779103
```

My code for the two lines is as following:

```
var line1 = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x1(d.year); })
            .y(function(d) { return y1(d.value1); });

var line2 = d3.line()
            .defined(function(d) { return d.value2 != undefined; })
            .x(function(d) { return x1(d.year); })
            .y(function(d) { return y1(d.value2); });

d3.tsv("js/plots/nitrogen-fertilisers.tsv"
, function(d) {
    d.value1 = +d.value1;
    d.value2 = +d.value2;
    return d;
}

fw1.append("path")
        .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#004494")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line1);

fw1.append("path")
        .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#7FA1C9")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line2);
```

The two lines are displayed but, as shown in the figure, the second series does not start from 2005 but from the beginning of the series with a segment that comes from x-axis.

[two lines plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l97J.png)

I don't know how to do in order to skip all missing null (or indefinite?) values before 2005. If I fill the missing data with null or NaN I obtain following error: "d3.v4.min.js:2 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL16,531L32,53…".
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the row function check if the value is set if not set it to undefined

```
d.value2 = (d.value2==="") ? null : +d.value2;
```